# Is the order of evaluation of AND operator from left to right guaranted?

Tags: c, for-loop, operators, operator-precedence, logical-and

I was studying the K&R "The C Programming Language" 2nd Edition book and in chapter 1.9 Character arrays on Page 29 there is an example program given to print out the longest line after reading a set of lines. In the program there is an example `getline()` function provided and within that function is a for loop that read characters and checks for validity and adds it to a character array if valid. The for loops is given as

```
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
```

My question is: What guarantees `(c = getchar()) != EOF` is evaluated before `c != '\n'`?

Of what I previously know of C, order of associativity is **not** same as order of evaluation, and the C standard does not specify order of evaluation. If so what happens if `c != '\n'` is evaluated before `(c = getchar()) != EOF`? It should check newline character with previous character rather than the currently read character since the `getchar()` operation is done after the check of newline character, right?

A quick google search shows that this kind of code is commonly written, so I suspect it will work if I try it myself. Also the book claims all example programs are working programs.

What guarantees the evaluation of `(c = getchar()) != EOF` before `c != '\n'`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Operator precedence and associativity doesn't have anything to do with it. [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172)

Comment: @Lundin I stupidly mixed up associativity with order of evaluation. I delete this stupid comment including this one, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, **the && operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation**; if the second operand is evaluated, there
> is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand
> is not evaluated.